# Pandas dataframe group month from years

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

in Python I have some rainfall data in .xls format with columns (rainfall) (year) from 1991 to 2015 (month) from 1 to 12 and I'd like to group the data by months instead of years. 
Here is a preview of the data:

```
  Rainfall (mm)     Year   Month   
         118.969    1991       1            
         202.265    1991       2            
         255.006    1991       3            
         170.505    1991       4            
         223.541    1991       5
```

And I would like to go to this:

```
      Rainfall (mm)     Year   Month   
             -          1991       1            
             -          1992       1            
             -          1993       1            
             -          1994       1            
             -          1995       1
```

Comment: `result = df.sort_values(by='Month')`

Comment: Update: this returns the rain values sorted by month but in disorder when considering the year. It'd be even greater if I could get it sorted from 1991 on. Any idea how?

Comment: Try `result = df.sort_values(by=['Month', 'Year'])`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot